# A field in math that describe the relation between the real world and it's representation in our minds

Tags: logic

is there any mathematical theory addressing any of the following questions : 
1.is there a math object that represent the fact that our knowledge about the internal world of other poeple is just a comparaison with our own ? 
for example  : we do not know what sadness mean to other poeple . we know what it means to us and we suppose that it means the same thing for other poeple. 
2.is there any mathematical representation of consciousness ?
3.is there any mathematical representation of real world objects as an identity carieng a set of properties ?
4.is there any mathematical representation of ideas as copies objects in the real world to objects in the internal world (ideas world) 
5. what field of math (if there is one at all) deal with such questions ?

Comment: Isn't it basically philosophy of maths? (I am no expert at all, but I'm pretty sure that the work mathematicians produce is kind of far from these interrogations. As a hobby or part time activity, they may think about it though.)

Comment: @Suzet More like philosophy *period*.

Comment: You will probably not find your answers in mathematics, if at all. Most of this sounds as being more about philosophy or psychology.

Comment: Do you mean [quantum brain dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_brain_dynamics) or [hierarchical temporal memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_temporal_memory)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.is there a math object that represent the fact that our knowledge about the internal world of other poeple is just a comparaison with
>   our own ? for example : we do not know what sadness mean to other
>   poeple . we know what it means to us and we suppose that it means the
>   same thing for other poeple.

There are parts of logic, which describe a group of agents and their knowledge and allow some reasoning. See [Common Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge_(logic)), [Epistemic modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modal_logic).

> 2.is there any mathematical representation of consciousness ?

I believe this is an open mystery. E.g. the popular [Gödel, Escher, Bach book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) did highlight [self-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reference) as a first step. See [Consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness#Scientific_study) for more pointers.

> 3.is there any mathematical representation of real world objects as an identity carieng a set of properties ?

Not sure what you mean. [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is popular for modeling 3D scenarios, and as such used heavily in games programming. The mathematical basis are a[bstract data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type), [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) and such.

> 4.is there any mathematical representation of ideas as copies objects in the real world to objects in the internal world (ideas world)

No idea.

> 5. what field of math (if there is one at all) deal with such questions ?

IMHO this would be rooted in computer science, more precise artificial intelligence.

The representations of knowledge and partial knowledge show up in probability theory and related branches of logic. Some philosophers are also active in those areas of logic.